# Understanding why a solution is wrong in a counting problem

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Given a $26\times26$ board, when rows are marked $1$-$26$ and columns are marked A-Z, and $52$ gaming blocks ($26$ are white and $26$ are black),

How many options are they, for placing the blocks on the board given the following conditions:

1. Each square can only contain one block.
2. Each row and each column must contain one block from each color.

So my solution was to look at the problem in two steps:

1. Choosing a square for a white block for each row, when we can't choose the same column twice: $26!$ options.
2. Repeating the process but this time each row has a square that is already taken, also we can't repeat the same column twice: $25!$.

Overall I've got $26!\cdot25!$ options. Now, I know that this is the wrong solution, but I couldn't understand why. It seems like it should work because we can't choose the same square twice, also the number of available columns is decreasing.

Comment: Very often, a good method for "Understanding why a solution is wrong in a counting problem" is to consider **a similar problem with smaller numbers**, where you can see what's going on because you can actually list all the cases. How many solutions do you get for $8$ blocks on a $4\times4$ board?

Comment: Without loss of generality, suppose the white squares went along the diagonal.  The punchline is that if when choosing where the black squares go row by row, if we chose the first black square to go in row1columnB then in row2 we still have $25$ options for where we could put our black square (*it couldn't go in row2colB since the white square is there, but it can go anywhere else*), but on the other hand if our first black square was anywhere else such as row1columnC, we only have $24$ options where we could put our black square (we can't put it row1columnB, and cant put in column from first)

Comment: Multiplication principle only works when we can guarantee that previously made choices  don't affect the quantity of choices available at later steps (*though the types of choices may change*).  That is not the case here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose where the white blocks go.  This is precisely what a permutation is and there are indeed $26!$ options.

Now... choose where the black squares go, noting that this will also be a permutation, but one that specifically avoids any of the previously used positions.  This is a special type of a permutation called a [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).  A common notation for derangements of $n$ elements is $!n$.

The answer here is:

$$26!\cdot !26$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider some fixed placement of white blocks.

If you place the black block in the first row in the column that has a white block in the second row, then you will have $25$ ways to place the black block in the second row.

If you place it in any other column, then you will only have $24$ ways to place a black block in the second row.

Hopefully this intuitively shows why your solution is wrong.